# Bread Crumbs Nav Links, Recursive Array, PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have a database table with two columns for page URL's and URL parents, like this:

URL | Parent
Animal | (null)
Mammal | Animal
Tiger | Mammal

I'm trying to convert it to PDO. This is the original script:

```
$TopnavTable = 'gz_life';
$TopnavName = 'Taxon';

function get_path($node, $TopnavTable, $TopnavName) {
$result = mysql_query('SELECT Parent FROM ' . $TopnavTable . ' WHERE ' . $TopnavName .  '="'.$node.'";');

 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $path = array();
 if ($row['Parent']!='') {
   $path[] = $row['Parent'];

  $path = array_merge(get_path($row['Parent'], $TopnavTable, $TopnavName), $path);
  }
 return $path;
}

switch ($MyPage)
{
 case 'ChildPage':
 $TopNav = str_replace('Carnivora', '', $TopNav);
 break;
 default:
 break;
}

$mypath = get_path($MyURL, $TopnavTable, $TopnavName);
$MyLink = $mypath;
$MyLink = str_replace('Life', '', $MyLink);
$MyDisplay = $mypath;
for($i=0;$i<count($mypath);$i++){
$TopNav = "<a href=\"".$MyLink[$i]."\"> ".$MyDisplay[$i]."</a>&nbsp;&gt;";
$That = array('<a href="Life">', '"> ', '&gt;', '<a href="');
$This = array('<a href="/Life/">', '">', '&gt; ', '<a href="/Life/');
$TopNav = str_replace($That, $This, $TopNav);
```

---

Someone just helped me upgrade a similar query, where the parent-child relationship is based on URL's. For example, the URL MySite/Topics/Washington/Governor should yield bread crumbs navigation links that look like this:

Topics > Washington > Governor

This is the code:

```
$TopnavTable = 'pox_topics';
$TopnavName = 'URL';

function get_path($dbh,$node,$TopnavTable, $TopnavName) {
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name FROM $TopnavTable WHERE $TopnavName = ?");
 $stmt->bindValue(1,$node);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
 $row = $stmt->fetch();  
 $path = array_merge(get_path($pdo,$row['Parent'], $TopnavTable, $TopnavName), $path);
 return  $path ;  
}

$Path2 = explode("/", $path);
$arrlength=count($Path2);
$html ='<a href="/Topics">'.$Path2[0].'</a> > ';//First Member
for($x=1;$x<$arrlength-1;$x++)  {//Between first & last
 $html .= '<a href="/Topics/'.$Series.''.$Path2[$x].'">'.$Path2[$x].'</a> > ' ;
}
$html .= '<span class="navHere"><b>'.$Path2[$x].'</b></span>'; //Last member
$html = str_replace('/'.$MySection.'/'.$MySection.'', '/'.$MySection.'', $html);
echo $html ;
```

I was advised to read up on hierarchical data @ http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ In fact, I think that's what my original script posted at the top is based on.

Anyway, I thought I could modify the PDO script above to make it work with my hierarchical DB table, but I've been striking out, as usual.

Can anyone tell me what I need to change? (I deleted $Path2 = explode("/", $path); of course, but I never made any progress beyond that.)

Comment: See `The path to the root: the breadcrumb trail` in this [**tutorial**](http://sqllessons.com/categories.html)

Comment: $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT :MyURL as node_name,
  up1.Taxon as up1_Taxon,
  up2.Taxon as up2_Taxon,
  up3.Taxon as up3_Taxon
  from gz_life as node
 left outer
  join gz_life as up1
   on up1.Taxon = :MyParent
 left outer
  join gz_life as up2
   on up2.Taxon = up1.Parent
 left outer
  join gz_life as up3
   on up3.Taxon = up2.Parent
 GROUP BY up1.Taxon
 ORDER BY node_name
   ");
$stm->execute(array(
     'MyURL'=>$MyURL,
     'MyParent'=>$MyParent
));

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $Taxon1 = $row['up1_Taxon'];
 $Taxon2 = $row['up2_Taxon'];
 $Taxon3 = $row['up3_Taxon'];
}

Comment: I posted the query I wound up with. It seems to work fine, though it's not the same query used in the tutorial.

I was confused until I realized that the tutorial uses a table with two numerical keys, id and parentid. My table has just one.

But I discovered that I could still make the table work if I supply values for two variables - $MyURL (the URL of a particular web page, which matches a value in my table.field gz_life.Taxon) and $MyURL's Parent. So if I view the URL MySite/Life/Canis_lupus (the wolf), its parent should be Canis, its grandparent Canidae and its great grandparent Carnivora.

Comment: I had a problem with the script displaying multiple results (e.g. CarnivoraCarnivoraCarnivoraCarnivora), but I discovered that I could fix it by adding GROUP BY (up1.Taxon, up2.Taxon or up3.Taxon but not plain "Taxon").

One trivial question: Why do I have to create the value $MyParent? I can also supply a specific value:

on up1.Taxon = 'Canis'

But it seems like this ought to work as well:

on up1.Taxon = node.Parent

But it doesn't work, and I couldn't find anything else that does work. I guess it's no big deal, since I derive the value for $MyParent from another query anyway.

Comment: I use a version of  `The Nested Set Model` in this [**tutorial**](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). This doesn't require the depth of the node as in the query you are using. eMail me (see my profile) for details

Comment: @David - Yes, I'd love to know more about that script. However, I can't find your e-mail address on your profile or website. Alternatively, you can find my e-mail address at www.geobop.org/Contact